# Customer be able to set amount in my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal

I've been trying to generate a form to allow customer write the Amount to pay via paypal in my webpage..  I generated an amount editable javascript button then used the generated code to write and stylish my own.

And also I have the next javascript code to update the amount paypal field and make sure if customer clears the non hidden field (thisisit), it sets amount with the minimum, so customer not be able to edit the Amount on Paypal Secure page at checkout. In other words, the less that a customer can enter in my site is 100 MXN.

What I want to know is if I'm safe to include the code below in a HTML Wix control to start receiving payments? Or
Should I Encrypt to do something else to secure the amount to be changed hackers. In that case.. I would like to read a step by step way to do that starting from what I already have in this post.

Here is the snippet of my button

```js
(function($) {
$.fn.currencyInput = function() {
   this.each(function() {
   var wrapper = $("<div class='currency-input' />");
   $(this).wrap(wrapper);
   $(this).before("<span class='currency-symbol'>$</span>");
         $(this).ready(function() {
                   var f1 = document.getElementById("thisisit");
           var f2 = document.getElementById("amount");
                  f2.value = f1.value * 1.04;
         });
         
   $(this).change(function() {
   var min = parseFloat($(this).attr("min"));
      var max = parseFloat($(this).attr("max"));
      var value = this.valueAsNumber;
             //alert($(this).val().length);
      if($(this).val().length <= 0 || value < min)
       value = min;
      else if(value > max)
       value = max;
      $(this).val(value.toFixed(2)); 
             var f2 = document.getElementById("amount");
             f2.value = value * 1.04;
             //alert(f1.value);
             //alert(f2.value);
   });
   });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.currency').currencyInput();
});
```

```css
         .currency {
            padding-left:12px;
        }

        .currency-symbol {
            position:absolute;
            padding: 0px 3px;
        }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" class="paypal-button" target="_top">
    <div class="hide" id="errorBox"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="button" value="paynow">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Pago a Reserva">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="MXN">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" class="paypal-input" id="amount" name="amount" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="My success payment webpage at my WIX web site">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="es_XC">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="YOURPAYPALID">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="JavaScriptButton_paynow">
    <input type="hidden" name="env" value="www">
    <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
        <table style="font-family:Verdana;">
            
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="No. Reserva" />No. Reserva</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >
                    <input style="font-size:12px" type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200" title="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Importe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="number" id="thisisit" class="currency" min="100.00" max="200000.00" value="100.00"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_paynow_LG.gif" border="0" onclick="" name="submit" alt="PayPal, la forma más segura y rápida de pagar en línea." />
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the best way to secure against value manipulation with PayPal is PayPal IPN.
PayPal IPN lets you check for example if the minimun quantity is 100 and if not dont proceed with the payment

Check this link [Paypal IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

Check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129884/4270737) maybe it helps

UPDATE: Try to create a donate button [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/popup/DonateButton-outside) and try the advanced options maybe PayPal allows to set a minimun quantity for the donation or whatever type of payment.

Comment: Hi.. thank you for your answer.. I'm a very very new on this.. Actually very very new on Web Development. This solution seems too complex for me at this point. And actually I don't really want to process the payment in my site.. I just want the customer be able to set the Amount in the field I display for himn and it to be safe for me and him. The rest of the process is the common we know where you are redirected to a paypal checkout page like this https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and then the customer can enter paypal credentials and proceed with the purchase.